# Django allauth: how would you create a typical /accounts/settings page while leveraging what allauth already gives us?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-allauth

I have setup allauth and noticed it exposes `/accounts/password/change/` which is a lovely form to change the currently logged in user's password. It also exposes `/accounts/email/` which is fantastic for handling all of the craziness associated to linking e-mail addresses to an account.

My question is:

**How can I create the notion of an `/accounts/settings/` page** which would act as a typical settings page for the user so they can edit their name, change their e-mail info or update their password all through 1 template?

I believe the first step would be to create a `settings` application then hookup an `/accounts/settings` route that is login protected, create a view to handle a form submission and display the other templates that allauth provides but I'm just not sure how to get everything together at the view level.

I think it would probably be a good idea to have (3) separate forms on this page. One for changing passwords, the second for handling all of the e-mail business that allauth provides and finally the third form would be for handling custom information like updating their name and whatever else you might have in an extended user model?

Answer (score 0):

Well its simple, The allauth account templates extends `account/base.html` which extends `base.html` So you can edit `account/base.html` to have the left menu as a navigation and right side content will change based on the user selection, placed this in your project templates `account/base.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load url from future %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3 columns">
            <div class="well">
                <h3>{% trans "Account" %}</h3>
                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                        <li><a href="{% url "profile_edit" %}">{% trans "Profile" %}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url "account_change_password" %}">{% trans "Change password" %}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url "socialaccount_connections" %}">{% trans "Social Connections" %}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url "account_email" %}">{% trans "Manage Email Accounts" %}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span9 columns">
                <div class="well">
                    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Now the above template will act as a settings page. For example you can set `profile_edit` as default url for settings page, and when the user is going to land on the page it will looks something like this:

[image]

I have used bootstrap layout just for demonstration. Also pay close attention to the block names within templates, you may have different depending on yours `base.html`.